# Multiple File Uploads with Perl CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a simple web form in which I want the user to select a folder to upload (I only care about the contents of the folder). So my attempt to make this work is as followed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header;

my $upload_folder = '/var/www/html/uploads';
my $name = $q->param('name');
my $email = $q->param('email');
my $comments = $q->param('comments');
my @files = $q->param('multi_files');

foreach my $upload(@files){
    print "Upload this please -- $upload<br>";
    my $upload_file  = $q->upload($upload);
    if ($upload_file){
        open (OUTFILE,">$upload_folder/$upload") or die $!;;
        binmode OUTFILE;
        while (<$upload_file>) {
            print OUTFILE;
        }
    }
    else {
        print "<b>Guess it's broken</b><br/>";
    }
}

print "<p><b>Name</b> -- $name<br><b>Email</b> -- $email<br><b>Comments</b> -- $comments<br>";

print $q->end_html;
```

When I run the script all the parameters are correct, the files print out as expected but when I execute the upload query it returns blank. This is my first attempt at using CGI as I tend to use other languages to process forms.

Here is the code from the form just in case :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stupid Test Site</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test</h1>

        <form action="/cgi-enabled/test.pl" method="POST">
            Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Select PO folder: <input name="multi_files" type="file" webkitdirectory multiple /><br/>
            Comments:<br>
            <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also posted this question on perlmonks.com as well.

Comment: Please inform all sites when you [cross-post](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1184466).

Comment: k, I've updated this question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with my code was it was missing the

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

from the form.  I made some changes as well.  Here is my working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );
use HTML::Entities qw/encode_entities/;
use File::Copy qw' copy ';
use File::Basename;

my $q = new CGI;
print $q->header;

my $upload_folder = '/var/www/html/uploads';

my $name = $q->param('name');
my $email = $q->param('email');

my $comments = $q->param('comments');
my @files = $q->param('multi_files');
my @io_handles=$q->upload('multi_files');

my %file_hash;

foreach my $item(@files){
    next unless $item =~ /.+\/(M.+\.pdf)/;
    foreach my $sub_item(@io_handles){
        if($item eq $sub_item){
            $file_hash{$item} = $sub_item;
        }
    }
}

chdir $upload_folder or die "Cannot chdir to upload destination directory: $!\n";

print '<ul>';
foreach my $key(keys %file_hash){
    my $base = basename($file_hash{$key});#    
    my $tmpfilename = $q->tmpFileName($file_hash{$key});
    my $destFile = File::Spec->catfile($upload_folder,$base);
    copy( $tmpfilename, $destFile ) or die "Copy to ($destFile) failed: $!\n";
    print '<li>Sucessfully uploaded --- <b>', CGI->escapeHTML(basename($key)), '</b></li>';
}
print '</ul>';

print "<p><b>Name</b> -- $name<br><b>Email</b> -- $email<br><b>Comments</b> -- $comments<br>";

print $q->end_html;
```

Thanks for the help.  (I posted this answer on perlmonks.com as well)